# Context path in Tomcat vs Context path in Glassfish

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, glassfish, context.xml

I generated a war file for my app in windows - glassfish, and I'm trying to deploy this war in Tomcat on linux server. The deploy goes fine and it works too but when I bring in Apache as a proxy for Tomcat, somehow the 'context' is not getting set properly. Is it because in Glassfish context is stored in sun-web.xml but in Tomcat its diff ?

How can I fix this ?